# applying additional ngclass expression on table header

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to set the background colour of a column based on ngclass expression. I already have an existing expression. How do I add additional expression. If you see my code below I am looping through column names and applying ngclass expression

```
<table id="LegalFundClass" class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
                    <tr *ngFor="let c of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassColumnNames">
                        <ng-container
                            *ngIf="c !='Hurdle Rate Basis' && c != 'Hurdle Rate %' && c != 'Hurdle Rate Index' || isHurdle;">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="c !='Clawback %' || isClawback">

                                <th
                                    [ngClass]="c != 'Space1' && c != 'Space2' && c != 'Space3' && c != 'Buttons' ? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor'">
                                    {{ c }}</th>
```

I need also add the following expression. How do I do that

```
c== 'TERMS' apply class mainheading
```

Comment: Try this `<th [ngClass]="(c != 'Space1' && c != 'Space2' && c != 'Space3' && c != 'Buttons' ? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor')
&& (c== 'TERMS' ? 'mainheading' : '')">{{ c}}</th>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code for multiple condition

```
 <th [ngClass]="[c != 'Space1' && c != 'Space2' && c != 'Space3' && c != 'Buttons' ? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor', 
c == 'TERMS' ? 'mainheading' : '']">{{ c }}</th>
```